# Controle de transações aplicação rest no spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, transações

Estava estudando um pouco sobre a anotação **@Transactional** (versão feita pelo Spring), e me surgiu uma dúvida. De acordo com uma [publicação feita no DevMedia](https://www.devmedia.com.br/conheca-o-spring-transactional-annotations/32472), a "*forma mais correta*" de se usar é anotando no nosso método de negócio, pois ali pode ter várias ações no banco, e não uma só em específica. Então, pensei comigo, se em minha aplicação RestFull, não seria mais viável anotar o logo o endpoint (que só faz a chamada de um método) para fazer uma transação de tudo o que tiver dali pra frente. Exemplo:

```
    @PostMapping
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public Response< ? > criarNovaViagem(@RequestBody ViagemRequest novaViagem) throws ViagemServiceApplicationException {
        return new Response<>(true, this.viagemService.criarViagem(novaViagem), null);
}
```

Este método "`criarNovaViagem()`" faz N operações em N tabelas diferentes. É errado ou "porco" eu anotar meu endpoint com `@Transacional`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É uma questão de responsabilidade, que por sua vez reflete em flexibilidade e evita vários outros problemas.

O `Controller` não deveria conhecer nada do banco de dados, muito menos abrir uma transação com o banco de dados. Sua responsabilidade é pegar as informações da requisição HTTP e passar para as demais classes (Services), controlando a chamada de classes e obtendo ao final o resultado para passar para o usuário da aplicação.

O que cada `Service` faz é responsabilidade apenas dela. Algumas podem salvar/consultar algo no banco de dados, outras podem fazer operações em ambientes externos (integrações), etc. Ou seja, não faz sentido abrir uma transação para todo mundo abaixo do `Controller` sendo que ele não faz ideia do que os Services irão precisar.

Quais as consequências quando se desrespeita isto?:

- Se existir alguma integração com ambiente externo e esta integração apresentar algum problema de `timeout`, toda a transação ficará esperando esta integração que não tem nenhuma relação com banco de dados.
- Se precisar persistir algo no banco de dados antes de fechar esta transação do `Controller`, você não conseguirá. Se tiver algum `Service` que faz isto ou que gostaria que fizesse, ele será prejudicado.

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser ruim do ponto de vista arquitetural e de separação de responsabilidades.

O seu controller, por definição, não deveria saber de detalhes de processos relativos a persistência em banco de dados nem servir de ponte para tráfego dessas informações.

Esse papel cabe à camada de serviços (ela sim, a ponte entre persistência e entrada de dados) e é por isso que, tradicionalmente, aconselha-se a colocar nela essa anotação.